# Bind_param() Output

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bindparam

I want to expand a query in a foreach loop. I'm doing it without bind_param(), which causes errors, probably because my values include commas which i do not want to remove.
I want to Insert multiple rows with one Query. Is there a Way to use bind_param() in this context?

Code now looks like:

```
$finalquery = "INSERT INTO mytable (a,b) VALUES";
foreach($xml->entry) {
    $abc_a = $xml->schema;
    $abc_b = $xml->schema->a;
    if($count == 1){
         $finalquery .= "($abc_a,$abc_b)"
    }else($count == 1){
         $finalquery .= ",($abc_a,$abc_b)"
    }
    //COUNT UP
}
$result = $mysqli->query($finalquery) or die ("ERROR: ($finalquery)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep in mind that when building a query like this, This way i am inserting multiple rows in my single table.

```
$values = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $qvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $values[] = "($field1, $field2, $field3, $qvalue)"; // quoted value, not the raw value
}

$query_values = implode(',', $values);

$query = "INSERT INTO tablename(field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES $query_values";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
```

Comment: First of all: thanks for you answer.
so the query would be something like: 
"Insert into tablename(field1, field2, field3, field4) values (abc,def,ghi,jk),(acb,fed,ghgi,ik),(...,...,...,..)" right? 

Problem is, that my values have commas and i need to keep them. I thought that i could use bind_param() but i don't know how to use it for inserting multiple rows.